# Why is this atm put twice as much as the call?

Tags: stocks, options

The stock is BYND. It's put has been costing twice as much as the call ... roughly 10.85 and 5.00 respectively at the moment. What could cause this. I should also point out that the stock is up 5 percent after hours, so whoever bought this put doesn't seem to be doing to well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be talking about the $120 put and call expiring January 17. The option prices you cite were as of the regular market close, when BYND was trading around $114. Thus, these were not *at-the-money* (ATM) options and it is no surprise that the put was priced higher than the call. After hours, as you note, BYND climbed to around $120, but the options did not continue to trade and so those quotes became stale.